# Sort problem with first position

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have much count of items in MySQL database, and they must be shown on a web page. But, element, which set up earlier, must be first of whole data array. Currently, data recevied from Mysql sorted by creation time. Also, every item has a unique ID, which store in settings table. May be you help me to solve this little trouble.

UPDATE:

this php-array basically demonstrate my db structure

```
    array(
       0=>array(
          "id"=>1,
           "name"=>"xyz"
       ),
       1=>array(
           id"=>3,
           "name"=>"abc"
       ),
       2=>array(
           id"=>5,
           "name"=>"asdfbc"
       )
    );
```

UPDATE 2

I need to sort previous array. For example, first element must be item with id = 3, after elements must be sort by time creation (desc or asc). Time field (timestamp) exist, but I'm too lazy for add it :-)

Comment: Can you show us what code you have?

Comment: you mean, you want to sort the rows by set-up time before creation time?

Comment: I can set up first element in setting, and after use it for sort.

Comment: much count=a lot. I wasn't able to decode the rest.

Comment: yi_H, tnx a lot ^_^ I'm just learning eng, sorry for my broken lang... ;-(

Comment: we would like to help you but it's a bit hard if we don't understand what the question is. try to rephrase it, maybe add some more code to show what you have now and what you would like to have.

Comment: yi_H, I've add an example, I hope it's help you for understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, IF(`id`=3,0,1) AS `sticky` FROM `test` ORDER BY `sticky` ASC, `timestamp` DESC
```